# How to divide irregular polygon into equal areas

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, splitting, create

I am seeking to divide this 200 acre polygon into 5 polygons of 40 acres.  I have yet to find a concrete solution to this task by searching this forum.  Is there a pragmatic tool in existence that can help accomplish this task?  I am using ArcGIS 10.5.  I have attempted the fishnet tool but all that accomplished was create a grid.  Another suggestion I found (The Parcel Editor toolbar) is unavailable with my current license.
[image]

Comment: See my answer to: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212967/split-polygons-into-equal-areas-within-each-region/213443

Comment: I have reopen this question because it refers to ArcGIS solutions rather than QGIS solutions, which makes this a unique question. @BERA You may want to consider adding your excellent answer to this post instead.

Answer (score 2):

ArcGIS Pro has a tool called [Subdivide Polygon (Data Management)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/subdivide-polygon.htm) that does what you are after. In this example, the polygon on the left is split into 5 equal parts and the 7 polygons on the right are split into 5 equal parts using the `STACKED_BLOCKS` option.

[image]